# Query: Find string in database field

Tags: php, mysql, database

In my database table, I have three fields. Let's say the fields names are name,age, and favorite_numbers.

Now, the contents of my database are as follows:

1. Anna is 15 and her favorite numbers are "14,21,16"
2. Jessica is 20 and her favorite numbers are "21,30,20"
3. Sara is 30 and her favorite numbers are "50,45,21"
4. Jessa is 12 and her favorite numbers are "10,12,20"
5. Farrah is 19 and her favorite numbers are "6,12,20"

How do I formulate my query in order to view the names of the people whose has the favorite number of 21?

In the contents above, I wanted to display Anna, Jessica and Sara's names only since the three of them has the favorite number of 21.

Comment: if favorite_numbers is a varchar, you'll need something like "select name from table where favorite_number like %21%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query : 
i imagine that your table name is `user` (you didn't give the table name).

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE favorite_numbers like '%21%'
```

Comment: Oh i forgot the table name. Sorry,my bad. Anyway, thanks for this. I forgot the use of % again. Thanks mate (y) ;)

Comment: This is not correct, as it will also include numbers like 121 and 211 etc.

Comment: Oh ya,, you right astander. i didn't notice it. But if the `favorite_numbers` is not more than 100, i think we can use it.. :D

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at using [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
>   string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
>   string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the
>   first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type
>   SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic.
>   Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string.
>   Returns NULL if either argument is NULL.

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c11e9/2)

Please note that using

```
WHERE nums LIKE '%21%'
```

will not work, as that would then also include 211 and 121